# HtmlEditorExtender inside Repeater all Toolbar button missing icon

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I have textbox and HtmlEditorExtender inside the Repeater Item, the rendering went all wrong! Anybody has any idea how to solve this?

[image: Problem]

Below is the sample code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestion" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="colTitle">
                        Question <%# Eval("sequence") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="colColon">:</div>
                    <div class="colContent">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("questionText") %>' 
                            TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="10" CssClass="textbox">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="tbxQuestion_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server"
                            TargetControlID="tbxQuestion" DisplaySourceTab="true">
                        </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptAnswer" runat="server" DataSource="<%# GetAnswers(Container.DataItem) %>">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="colTitle" style="text-align:right">
                                Answer <%# Eval("sequence") %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="colColon">:</div>
                            <div class="colContent">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("answerText") %>'
                                    TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="10" CssClass="textbox">
                                </asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="tbxAnswer_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" 
                                    TargetControlID="tbxAnswer" DisplaySourceTab="true">
                                </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by added a dummy HTML editor outside of the UpdatePanel to enable correct rendering all the time. The HTML editor is set to absolute and away from the screen.